# Cannot find the asymmetric key -- because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I am trying to be able to run a .Net dll through SQL using the CLR - I am doing so unsuccessfully.

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.sqlclr.net/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/9/Default.aspx)

So I am doing the following:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY AKEY_SqlClr FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\dlls\mySqlClr.dll'
```

Which works fine and creates the Key, then I try to do the following:

```
CREATE LOGIN SQLCLR_AsymKeyLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY AKEY_SqlClr
```

And I get the error:

> Cannot find the asymmetric key 'AKEY_SqlClr', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

How could I not have permissions to this?  I have verified that I have CREATE LOGIN permissions.  Any ideas?

Comment: My memory on this is a bit hazy... Are you creating it in the `master` database? Make sure to `USE master;` before creating your key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Logins are server principals and as such they cannot be created from keys stored in user databases. You must create the key from assembly in `master` database:

```
use master;
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY AKEY_SqlClr FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\dlls\mySqlClr.dll';
CREATE LOGIN SQLCLR_AsymKeyLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY AKEY_SqlClr;
```

Comment: One thing I found from this answer was that trying to create the key in the master database from an SNK file (using `FROM FILE` instead of `FROM EXECUTABLE FILE`) instead of the DLL results in: `Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.`.  However, using the DLL is better for me anyway as it means I don't have to move an snk file around with it to have it be registerable in databases.